# Format APNS-style JSON message in Python for use with Amazon SNS

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I'm creating an iOS app, and for our push notifications, we're using Amazon's Simple Notification Service (SNS).

SNS is wonderful, but the documentation is pretty sparse. I'm using [boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/sns.html), Amazon's Python library, and I've figured out how to send plain-text push notifications:

```
device_arn = 'MY ENDPOINT ARN GOES HERE'
plain_text_message = 'a plaintext message'
sns.publish(message=plain_text_message,target_arn=device_arn)
```

However, what's not clear from the documentation is how to create an an Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) message. I need to send a sound and a badge along with the push notification, but can't figure out how to format the JSON for the message.

Here's my best guess so far:

```
message = {'default':'default message', 'message':{'APNS_SANDBOX':{'aps':{'alert':'inner message','sound':'mySound.caf'}}}}
messageJSON = json.dumps(message,ensure_ascii=False)
sns.publish(message=messageJSON,target_arn=device_arn,message_structure='json')
```

When I run this code, though, all I see on the notification is "default message" - which means that Amazon SNS rejected my message's format, and displayed the `default` instead.

**How do I format this JSON correctly?**

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I figured it out! 
**Turns out, the APNS payload has to be encoded as a string within the larger payload** - and it totally works.

Here's the final, working code:

```
apns_dict = {'aps':{'alert':'inner message','sound':'mySound.caf'}}
apns_string = json.dumps(apns_dict,ensure_ascii=False)
message = {'default':'default message','APNS_SANDBOX':apns_string}
messageJSON = json.dumps(message,ensure_ascii=False)
sns.publish(message=messageJSON,target_arn=device_arn,message_structure='json')
```

**Here's a walkthrough of what's going on in this code:**

First, create the python dictionary for APNS:

```
apns_dict = {'aps':{'alert':'inner message','sound':'mySound.caf'}}
```

Second, take that dictionary, and turn it into a JSON-formatted string:

```
apns_string = json.dumps(apns_dict,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Third, put that string into the larger payload:

```
message = {'default':'default message','APNS_SANDBOX':apns_string}
```

Next, we encode *that* in its own JSON-formatted string:

```
messageJSON = json.dumps(message,ensure_ascii=False)
```

The resulting string can then be published using boto:

```
sns.publish(message=messageJSON,target_arn=device_arn,message_structure='json')
```

Comment: I'm using the C# SDK and the key missing thing for me, in addition to JSON'ing the APS content was to set MessageStructure = "json"... once I did that all was well.  THX

Comment: I adapted this to GCM, which I was having trouble with. Worked like a charm. Pasting my code for reference:

Answer (score 6):

When I use the SNS publish tool it autogenerates JSON that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "default": "<enter your message here>", 
    "email": "<enter your message here>", 
    "sqs": "<enter your message here>", 
    "http": "<enter your message here>", 
    "https": "<enter your message here>", 
    "sms": "<enter your message here>", 
    "APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"<message>\",\"sound\":\"default\"} }", 
    "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"<message>\" } }", 
    "ADM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"<message>\" } }" 
 }
```

This looks closer to the spec talked about by apple in their "[Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)" section. Where they state that the message should be

```
a JSON dictionary object (as defined by RFC 4627). 
This dictionary must contain another dictionary identified by the key aps.
The aps dictionary contains one or more properties
```

Have you tried providing a message closer to that specification? Something like this for instance:

```
{
    'default':'default message', 
    {
        'aps':{
            'alert':'inner message',
            'sound':'mySound.caf'
         }
    }
 }
```

Or following the example from the publish SNS publish tool:

```
{
    'default':'default message',
    'APNS': {
        'aps':{
            'alert':'inner message',
            'sound':'mySound.caf'
         }\
     }
 }
```

Maybe also using their backslash escaping.

Comment: The answer turned out to be that the APNS object needed to be encoded as a string, rather than a sub-JSON dictionary inside the larger message object. Thank you for the write-up, though!

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense seeing as the quotes are escaped in the SNS example from Amazon.