# Send text messages from web application to Android device using Amazon SNS

Tags: android, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm using AWS SNS to push messages to Android devices. Is there a way to send text message from a web application preferably *Django* to an Android device ? I tried using the *boto* library but there isn't an example in the documentation for pushing a message to a device. Can someone please point me in the right direction or help me figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

SNS sends email or *push messages* to phones. It does not send SMS.

You'll need to use a service like Twilio for that.

Comment: Yes, I meant push messages. Can you help me to push messages from a web app to my android chat app

Comment: [here are some examples of using boto for SNS pushes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20134162/659298)

Comment: Amazon SNS support sending text messages to phones.